# Error "latitude or longitude exceeded limits" when importing CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, error, latitude-longitude, import

I am currently working on a project with *"on the fly"*-projection (WGS 84 / UTM zone 32U).

I want to import a CSV file. file with points that have a **longitude and latitude** using the "Add Delimited Text Layer"-tool. In the tool I have to select a **CRS**. I tried this with several CRS's.

At first, the points will not show up correctly, but if I manually select a random CRS, then the points will show up correctly.

If I zoom out, the following Error will appear:

> Error: "latitude or longitude exceeded limits"

I already read, that this might happen because of the lon&lat and a projected CRS, but this does not help me up to now.

This is how my CSV file looks like:
[image: csv-file]

Comment: caa you show us how the first lines of the csv look like?

Comment: I added a screenshot. Nevertheless, I do not think that the .csv-file causes the problem. I still think it has something to do with the project's CRS. I was able to load the file into a project without "on the fly"-projection and it seemed to work there.

Comment: try also to take out also the "other" field. it is repeated 3 times, and the first one has commas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to distinguish between the **project** CRS and the **layer** CRS.
Your data is in lat/lon degrees, so the **layer** CRS should be EPSG:4326, WGS84.

Your **project** CRS can be anything else. In most cases a projected CRS, where units are metres or feet. On-the-fly projection should always be activated.

Just be sure to check the "Decimal separator is comma" box when you have decimal commas in your coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: edit your .CSV file, changing DOT instead of COMMA in lat/lon fields...